# Concurrency in ElastiCache

Tags: concurrency, amazon-elasticache

Are there any patterns to deal with concurrency in ElastiCache?

I know transactions aren't supported of course, but are there any operations like upserts or "update-if" that return boolean values indicating if the operation "wins"?

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider a number of commands falling into that category.

BRPOPLPUSH (and non-blocking cousin RPOPLPUSH): take an item from one list and if successful, push the item onto another list and return it. I used this to implement queues for a distributed 'worker' setup. It's explained in the pattern section: http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush

HSETNX/MSETNX/SETNX: set a hash key or string key to a value if it does not exist already. http://redis.io/commands/setnx